# An analytic function on the complex plane minus a discrete set of points

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on the following question:

> Let $A$ be a discrete set of points in $\mathbb{C}$, and $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$ such that $f$ has a simple pole at each $a \in A$, and the residue of $f$ there is a positive integer $n(a)$.  Fix a point $z_0 \not\in A$, and for each $z \not\in A$ let $\gamma_z$ be a path in $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$ from $z_0$ to $z$.
>
> (i) Show that $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$ is connected.
>
> (ii) Show that $F(z) = \exp(\int\limits_{\gamma_z} f)$ is a well defined function of $z$ which is analytic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$.
>
> (iii) Show that $F$ has a removable singularity at each $a \in A$.

(i) is pretty clear, given two points $z, w \not\in A$, take the straight line segment from $z$ to $w$.  If this line intersects any points in $A$, it intersects only finitely many of them, so it's obvious we can perturb the line to avoid points of $A$.

For (ii), I can see how $F$ is well defined.  Namely if $\gamma_z'$ is another path from $z_0$ to $z$, then $\gamma_z \circ \gamma_z'$ is a closed curve containing say, $a_1, ... , a_t \in A$, so $\int\limits_{\gamma_z} f - \int\limits_{\gamma_z'} f$ is equal to $2\pi i[n(a_1) + \cdots n(a_t)]$.  It follows that $\exp(\int\limits_{\gamma_z} f - \int\limits_{\gamma_z'} f) = 1$.

But, I don't know how to show this function is analytic.  Any hint here?

Comment: The claim that a straight line segment intersects finitely many points of $A$ is incorrect. Think of discrete sets that look like $\left{ 1/n \right}$.

Comment: I think you can argue (i) as follows: Let $z, w$ be distinct points in the complex plane. We show there is a path connecting $z$ to $w$ avoiding $A$. Since the topology of $\mathbf{C}$ has a countable basis, the discrete set $A$ is countable and therefore forms a $0$-dimensional real smooth manifold. Think of the circle $S^1$ centered at $z$, viewed as a $1$-dimensional real smooth manifold. Now consider the 'dipole field' flowing from $z$ to $w$; these field lines partition the complex plane (or the Riemann sphere) into the images of paths from $z$ to $w$ in such a way that...

Comment: ...the paths are in $1-1$ correspondence with the directions around $z$ determined by elements of $S^1$. Summarizing, we may define a (clearly smooth) map from $A$ to $S^1$ sending a point $a$ in $A$ to the element of the circle defining the unique field line which passes through $a$. By Sard's theorem, the image has measure $0$ in $S^1$ and therefore there exist many paths connecting $z$ to $w$ along field lines and avoiding the discrete set $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Proof of* (iii): Assume $0\in A$ and $n(0)=n>0$. Then we have
$$f(z)={n\over z}+ g(z)$$ with $g$ analytic in some closed disk $D$ centered at $0$. Assume $z_0\in D$ for simplicity. The "pseudo-function"
$$\Phi(z):=\int_{\gamma_z} f(z)\>dz=n \log {z\over z_0}+\int_{z_0}^z g(z)\>dz$$ is defined only up to integer multiples of $2\pi i$. The (well defined) function
$$F(z):=\exp\bigl(\Phi(z)\bigr)=\left|z\over z_0\right|^n e^{in(\phi(z)-\phi(z_0))}\cdot e^{G(z)}$$
is then bounded when $z\to0$, and therefore has a removable singularity there.

Answer (score 3):

For (i) your argument looks fine. For (ii) your argument that $F$ is well defined looks good too, but I'm not sure why we need the residue to be positive at each point of $A;$  seems to me it's enough to assume the residue is in $\mathbb {Z}$ for each $a \in A.$ To show analyticity, fix $z\in \mathbb {C}\setminus A.$ Then for small $h,$ show that

$$\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h} = F(z)\frac{\exp (\int_{[z,z+h]}f(w)\,dw) - 1}{h},$$

where $[z,z+h]$ is the usual line segment path. The last fraction $\to f(z)$ as $h\to 0.$ Thus $F'(z) = F(z)f(z).$

I don't think (iii) is true unless $f$ has a simple pole at each point of $A.$ For example, suppose $f(z) = 1/z + 1/z^2.$ You can explicitly calculate $F$ in this case, and it has an essential singularity at $0.$ But if all singularities are simple poles, then you can show $|F(z)|$ is on the order of $|z-a|$ near each $a\in A.$ So not only does $F$ have a removable singularity at $a,$ it has a zero of order $1$ there.

Comment: You're right about $f$ having simple poles, I forgot to add that in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

A standard argument for
i): we show $\mathbb C- A$ is path-connected. Given that a discrete set of points in the plane must be countable, is this: take any two points $x,y$ in $\mathbb C -A$. There are uncountably-many some extra work you can show that there is a path that avoids $A$, then $A$ is path-connected, so connected.

2) By a corollary of Cauchy's theorem, the line integral of an analytic function in a simply-connected region is analytic. We can find a small tubular
neighborhood of the curve (since $A$ is discrete) $\gamma_z$ that avoids $A$,d this tubular neighborhood is a simply-connected region, so that $\int_{\gamma_z}f$ is analytic. Then $exp ^{\int_{\gamma_z}f}$ is the composition of analytic functions and soit is analytic.

3) For iii) I think you can use the fact that the residue is an integer to show
that f is bounded in a neighborhood of each $a \in A$ and then use Riemann removable singularity theorem to show the singularities are removable. Let me think it through some more.